# DiagrammeR creates "wrong" diagram in R

Tags: r

I have code that generates diagram with diagrammer library in R. For data source I use xlsx file that you can download at this [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ap9fKWoBFV2yak4Q16vTcOusyT8)

```
library("xlsx")
df <-xlsx::read.xlsx("animals.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

With first lines I'm importing a file in to R. Then using `col1` and `col2` to  create a diagram

```
uniquenodes <- unique(c(df$col1, df$col2))

library(DiagrammeR)

nodes <- create_nodes(nodes=seq(uniquenodes), type="number", label=uniquenodes)
edges <- create_edges(from=match(df$col1, uniquenodes), to=match(df$col2, uniquenodes), rel="related")
g <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes, edges_df=edges)
render_graph(g)
```

After code is used I get this picture:

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: what version of `DiagrammeR` are you using?  (`packageVersion("DiagrammeR")`.  When I use version 0.8.1, your code works just fine.  When using the most recent version (0.9.0) your code fails entirely as the API has changed somewhat.  Also, when I say it works find under 0.8.1, I'm assuming that I've recreated your data structure correctly. You haven't actually shown us what is in `df`, so we can't exactly reproduce your results.

Comment: Every time I use  DiagrammeR I get this warning message "package ‘DiagrammeR’ was built under R version 3.3.2 " and I use 3.3.1 version.  My df is xlsx file that you can download I have left a link

Comment: Aha!  Try adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `read.xlsx` call.

Comment: I see can you give me example of how to use this line `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

Change your data import code to:

```
df <-xlsx::read.xlsx("animals.xlsx", 
                     sheetIndex = 1, 
                     header = TRUE, 
                     encoding = "UTF-8",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

### Long Explanation

It seems that your columns are actually factors, not characters.  I will recreate your data frame here (I'm not using the `xlsx` package because I'm too lazy to make the system changes necessary to get it to install)

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Cat", "Dog", "Bird"),
                 col2 = c("Feline", "Canis", "Avis"))
uniquenodes <- unique(c(df$col1, df$col2))

uniquenodes
[1] 2 3 1
```

Using your code when the columns are factors results in the figure you obtained.  Your code will work as desired if the columns are character strings.  Notice the difference here:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Cat", "Dog", "Bird"),
                 col2 = c("Feline", "Canis", "Avis"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
uniquenodes <- unique(c(df$col1, df$col2))

uniquenodes

library(DiagrammeR)


nodes <- create_nodes(nodes=seq(uniquenodes), type="number", label=uniquenodes)
edges <- create_edges(from=match(df$col1, uniquenodes), to=match(df$col2, uniquenodes), rel="related")
g <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes, edges_df=edges)
render_graph(g)
```