# Diagrammer cannot create nodes in R

Tags: r, diagrammer

I currently have R version 3.2.2 with `DiagrammeR` R package. I get these two errors when trying to run the following code:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
nodes <- create_nodes(nodes = seq(uniquenodes), 
                      type = "number", 
                      label = uniquenodes)
```

> Error: could not find function "create_nodes"

```
edges <- create_edges(from = match(df$col1, uniquenodes), 
                      to = match(df$col2,uniquenodes), 
                      rel = "related")
```

> Error: could not find function "create_edges"

Comment: please run `packageVersion("DiagrammeR")`. The API changed recently, and if you are using `DiagrammeR` 0.9.0, you will need to switch to `create_node_df` (I think)

Comment: I use 0.9.0 version and used code line this: `nodes<-create_node_df(nodes=seq...` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below should be compatible with `DiagrammeR` 0.9.0.  The graph appears to have a different appearance than the one generated in [DiagrammeR creates "wrong" diagram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074547/diagrammer-creates-wrong-diagram-in-r/42075966#42075966).  I haven't played with `render_graph` in 0.9.0 very much, so am not yet sure how to get the earlier appearance.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("Cat", "Dog", "Bird"),
                 col2 = c("Feline", "Canis", "Avis"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
uniquenodes <- unique(c(df$col1, df$col2))

uniquenodes

library(DiagrammeR)

nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(uniquenodes), 
                        type="number", 
                        label=uniquenodes)
edges <- create_edge_df(from=match(df$col1, uniquenodes), 
                        to=match(df$col2, uniquenodes), 
                        rel="related")
g <- create_graph(nodes_df=nodes, 
                  edges_df=edges)
render_graph(g)
```

Comment: This helped me more than any of the examples in the docs, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't played with render_graph in 0.9.0 very much, so am not yet sure how to get the earlier appearance.

The different appearance comes from the argument `attr_theme` in function `create_graph`, which is set to "default". Setting it to NULL provides brings back the appearance, however, this can be further adjusted by using function `set_global_graph_attributes`, which for me only worked in combination with `magrittr:%>%` as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42676248/6816220