# Changing the layour direction in DiagrammeR 0.9

Tags: r, diagrammer

Does anyone know how to change the layout direction of a graph in Diagrammer 0.9?

I used to do it this way, but this appears not to be working anymore in the latest version.

```
create_graph(nodes_df, edges_df) %>%
        add_global_graph_attrs(attr = "rankdir",value =  "LR",attr_type =  "graph")
```

Answer (score 0):

See here for usage of `set_global_graph_attrs` and `magrittr::%>%`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42676248/6816220